# Iterate to div to get different input field and post it to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main div that have class models and in this div I have different input type I want to iterate through main div with class models and get the the different input fields and post it to my controller but end up with this error. ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined

```
$("#Visitor-form").on("submit", function () {
                    //Code: Action (like ajax...)
                    var slides = getElementsByClassName("models");
                    console.log(slides);
                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

                        var previsitor = [
                            { NIC: slides[0].value, V_Name: slides[0].value }
                        ];
                    }
                    previsitors = JSON.stringify({ 'things': previsitor });

                    $.ajax({
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/PreVisitor/addMultipleVisitor',
                        data: things,
                        success: function () {
                            $('#result').html('"Pass List<PreVisitor>" successfully called.');
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            $('#result').html(response);
                        }
                    });

                })
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: you are missing  `var slides =document.getElementsByClassName `

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use jquery stick with jquery

```
 var slides = $(".models");
```

you forgot the `document` object in your current syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you already use jquery why not use `$(".models")` instead. It should be document.getElementsByClassName("models") but jquery would be better for getting the same results across different browsers.